# Annoying postback and paging issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

I asked a similar question to this but the circumstances have changed.

I bind my gridview through code rather than on the source.

**The pagination works fine, but if I click a button on second page of the gridview (after pagination), the postback is causing the pagination to reset to page 1. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

Within my pageload i have set the !POSTBACK method as shown i.e if there is  postback event, then it shouldn't reset the grid but it does!

Heres the onload:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["usersName"] != null)
        {

            object a = Session["_id"];

            IDMaster = Convert.ToInt32(a);

            GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
            GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = true;

        }

        else
        {
            GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        }




        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           BindGrid();
        }
```

The BindGrid();

```
           SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connstring);
           SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Coffees ORDER BY coffeeName ASC", sqlcon);
           SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           adp.Fill(ds);
           GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
           GridView1.DataBind();
```

Page index method:

```
 protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        if(ViewState["searchTerm"] != null)
        {
            object a = ViewState["searchTerm"];
            string reloadTerm = a.ToString();

            setGrid(reloadTerm);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your gridview in `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` event

```
GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) 
{ 
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        if(ViewState["searchTerm"] != null)
        {
            object a = ViewState["searchTerm"];
            string reloadTerm = a.ToString();

            setGrid(reloadTerm);
       }
        BindGrid();
}
```

hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sadly this is now leaving me with the issue of when i click page 2, then gridview is disappearing.

Comment: Hi, just try to use your `BindGrid()` method instead of `DataBind()` in your event. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Again thanks for your help. I have tried the bind but still the paging is resetting back to 1 after a postback

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding grid view dynamically, Please remove

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

condition from page load. Grid view needs binding every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue. I forgot that after I add an item to my cart i was calling response.redirect to refresh the page....obviously this meant the page was recalled refreshing the page so the grid was always going to reset. Thanks again.